# What is the interpretation of the REML criterion when running lmer?

Tags: validation, hierarchical-data, lme4, mixed-models

I wanted to ask how to interpret the displayed REML criterion at convergence when running a HLM model using `lmer` function in `lme4` package? Is it better when it is smaller or larger? Is it comparable among different models for the same outcome variable?

Here is an example of the model:

```r
hlm_example <- lmer(BSMMAT01 ~ 1 + (1 | IDSCHOOL), data=data)
summary(hlm_example)
```

[Model Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ogWZ.png)

Comment: This question belongs on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com), not here. It might get migrated automatically if other high-rep users vote to close/migrate, or you could re-post it there (and delete here).  (Also, please edit your question to include the model output as text (in a code block), rather than as an image ...)